# Matlab system call

Tags: bash, matlab

If I want to call a script "filtermapq.sh" inside a matlab script. How would I go about calling it and then waiting for the script to finish before resuming the rest of the matlab code? I am not the best with matlab.

Currently I am using this command:

```
system(['./util/filtermapq.sh ' var1 var2 var3])
```

However, I don't think that the matlab code waits for this to finish before continuing.

Comment: I removed the answer included in your question only because 1) it is the Q&A form, 2) it was already written among the answers. Not with any destructive intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem in my line of code. The problem was that matlab was not interpreting spaces between the variables I was inputting and was instead stringing them all together in one large string. Where my script takes 3 variables. I hope this helps anyone in the future, the correct code is as below:

```
system(['./util/filtermapq.sh ' var1 ' ' var2 ' ' var3])
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that you found a solution, let me give you a bit more elegant one, which will make life easier for the future.

```
system(sprintf('./util/filtermapq.sh %s %s %s', var1, var2, var3))
```

This could also pass in numbers, for instance, or other cool stuff. Also, you could do this to help with debugging such issues.

```
command=sprintf('./util/filtermapq.sh %s %s %s',var1, var2, var3);
fprintf('%s\n',command);
system(command);
```

That will log out to the screen the exact command that you are attempting to run. If your system command doesn't work, copy/paste it into a command line window, see if it works there. If it doesn't figure out how to massage the text to make it work, and fix your code appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

A nice introduction: http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2010/05/17/calling-shell-commands-from-matlab/

---

**Edit**: Quote from the link.

> "By default [system] will pause the MATLAB execution until the system command exits."

Comment: Yes and from the link above: "By default [system] will pause the MATLAB execution until the system command exits."

Comment: So my question is how come what I am doing doesn't work? Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: Your argument passing looks suspicious to me. I think you should pass your arguments as a part of the string. Have you checked the output you get? See the documentation for `system`, http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/system.html

Comment: Nice that you found your answer "on your own". Accept of answer, please?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have the script create a temporary file when it starts and then remove that file at the end. Within matlab, you would simply run a `do... while` loop checking for that file. As soon as the file is removed, you know the process has completed.

Comment: This seems like a viable solution. I was hoping for something a bit more elegant haha. Thank you for the thought though. Wish I could up-vote it but I need 15 rep...

Comment: @Dan - upvote given, now you have 15 :)  I typically do these sorts of workarounds for one-off analyses, as it's often faster to implement than googling for the solution. In any event, welcome to SO, hope to see you around more often!